# Помогите получить аватарку участника сервера через пинг в discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord

есть команда

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.avatar)
```

пример использования: /avatar [пинг участника сервера]
она отправляет в чат ссылку на аватарку вызвавшего
У меня вопрос: как сделать, так, чтобы бот мог отправить ссылку на аватар человека при пинге его в аргументах команды
Пример: /avatar @Clyde
и после такого мне надо чтобы отправил бот ссылку на аватар пинганутого пользователя, в данном случае некого Clyde(условный пользователь)

**ОБЪЯСНИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА МНЕ, КАК НОВИЧКУ - БЕЗ class, Я НЕ ПОНИМАЮ КЛАССЫ В PYTHON**

Comment: Классы не понимаете, а ботов пишите? Может стоит сначала ознакомиться с основами языка? А вообще-то классы в этой задаче вряд ли понадобятся, так что вы зря боитесь ;)

Comment: Я просто изучаю фреймворк, собственно, для простых текстовых ботов классами вряд ли нужно усложнять программу. Классы могут понадобится для к примеру редактора текста или даже изображений.

Comment: Редактор текста можно написать и без классов. Классы нужны для улучшения структуры программы, но, пожалуй, в ботах они действительно не очень нужны.

Answer (score 0):

При исполнении slash-команды, происходит interaction-событие, привязанное к ней.
Соответственно получить аватар:

```py
interaction.message.mentions[0].avatar.url
```